# Setting overflow-y: hidden; causes the page to jump to the top in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

I've got some javascript which handles opening modal popups on my website, and it also sets the `overflow-y` property on the `<html>` element to `hidden`. In Chrome and IE this works as expected - the scrollbar hides, and the page behind the modal popup remains in the same scroll position. When the popup is closed, `overflow-y` is set to `scroll` and the page is in the same state and position as before.

However in Firefox, as soon as `overflow-y` is changed to `hidden` the page scroll position jumps to the very top, and so when the popup is closed the view has changed for the user - not ideal.

The problem can be seen [on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBLgJ/5/)

Is there any solution for this behaviour?

Comment: Seems to work just fine in FF 19.

Comment: I am facing the similar issue, how were you able to handle this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? If so, could you provide an answer? I'm about to lose my mind.

Comment: This was a while ago now but I believe this just went away with newer versions of firefox. If I check my old jsfiddle from the post in the latest FF/Windows it works fine.

Comment: Mobile safari ios v7 has the same behavior. If i add overflow:hidden to block it scrolls to the top automatically.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use `overflow: hidden` on `html`, only on `body`. 
I had the same problem but fixed it by removing `html`.

Instead :

`$('body, html').css('overflow', 'hidden');`

Do :

`$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');`

Comment: On iOS, this allows the overflowed content to still be scrollable.

Comment: On Chrome 74.0.3729.157, the content still jumps to the top of the the page.

Comment: I had `html { overflow-y: scroll }` from a `reset.css` stylesheet, removing that fixed the issue for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue
after checking it in the inspector window, I noticed that in the reset CSS, HTML is set to

```
HTML {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

you can fix this by setting it to

```
HTML {
    overflow-y: initial;
}
```

If you don't want to touch reset CSS or just comment it

plugin and code is absolutely fine

Comment: First setting it to initial doesn't help for me. When scrolling and then setting overflow to "hidden" I still see the scroll position being reset back to 0

Comment: Thank you, overflow-y: scroll was my issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

change modal position from absolute to fixed:

```
#mymodal {
    position: fixed
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of bugs in the different browsers and the functionality is all over the place so be careful modifying styles on body and html tags.

To solve this issue i had to wrap the body's content into its own element and apply the scrolling restriction on it:

```
var $content = $('<div/>').append($body.contents()).appendTo($body);
$content.css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
```

This is the only way i've been able to get this working consistently across different browsers and devices.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem. My fix was

```
/**
 * Store the scroll top position as applying overflow:hidden to the body makes it jump to 0
 * @type int
 */
var scrollTop;

$(selecor).unbind('click.openmenu').on('click.openmenu', function (e) {
    // Stuff...
    scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop() || $('html').scrollTop();
    $('body,html').css({overflow: 'hidden'});
});

$(selector).unbind('click.closemenu').on('click.closemenu', function (e) {
    // Stuff
    $('body,html').css({overflow: 'initial'}).scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

This however doesn't solve the problem of what happens if a user resize the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just saw your code and you used a link with href="#". That is most likely the cause. I'd suggest removing the href property or use a button for it.

You should consider that this might not be caused by the css itself.
In my case I opened my popup with a link: `<a href="#">open popup</a>`
So what actually caused the jump to the top was the "#" in the href property of the link.

I removed it and added a noscroll class to my html and body tag:

```
.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Keeping the body height 100% from the beginning solved the problem for me.

```
body{
   height:100vh;
   overflow:auto;
}
body.with-modal{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use body tag instead of html.

JS Fiddle :- **http://jsfiddle.net/SBLgJ/6/**

JS Change:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#middle a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');  
    });
});
```

CSS Change:-

```
body {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

There is a reported issue for such behavior. (https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/71)

Comment: This solution doesn't work at all in Google Chrome v35.0.1916.114 m